# sprintf during ISR causes crash?

Tags: crash, printf, interrupt, isr

I am trying to format a string and then print it out to an *LCD* during an *ISR*. The *ISR* functions correctly with `sprintf()` commented out; but when it is introduced the program crashes during the *ISR*.

```
void __ISR(_CHANGE_NOTICE_VECTOR, IPL1) CNIntHandler(void) {
    //more of my code later
    LATBINV = LEDC; //invert LEDC to a 1
    hw_msDelay(20);

    int buttons = read_buttons();
    decode_buttons(buttons, &g_step_mode, &g_step_dir, &g_motor_delay);

    LATBINV = LEDC; //reinvert LEDC to 0

    mCNClearIntFlag(); //clear the CN flag
}
```

The `sprintf()` occurs within the `decode_buttons(`) fucntion:

```
void decode_buttons(int f_buttons, int *f_step_mode, int *f_step_dir, int *f_motor_delay) {
    char f_mode_str;
    char f_dir_str;
    int f_RPM;
    char f_LCD_str;

    switch(f_buttons) {
        case 0x0000: //none pressed
            *f_step_mode = HS;
            f_mode_str = "HALF";
            *f_step_dir = CW;
            f_dir_str = "CW";
            *f_motor_delay = 20; // semipermanent value
            f_RPM = 15;
            break;

        case 0x0040: //BTN 1 pressed
            *f_step_mode = FS;
            f_mode_str = "FULL";
            *f_step_dir = CW;
            f_dir_str = "CW";
            *f_motor_delay = 40;
            f_RPM = 15;
            break;

        case 0x0080: // BTN 2 pressed
            *f_step_mode = HS;
            f_mode_str = "HALF";
            *f_step_dir = CCW;
            f_dir_str = "CCW";
            *f_motor_delay = 30;
            f_RPM = 10;
            break;

        case 0x00C0: //Both pressed
            *f_step_mode = FS;
            f_mode_str = "FULL";
            *f_step_dir = CCW;
            f_dir_str = "CCW";
            *f_motor_delay = 24;
            f_RPM = 25;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    sprintf(f_LCD_str, "%s %s %d", f_dir_str, f_mode_str, &f_RPM);
    LCD_puts(f_LCD_str); //output string to LCD

    return;
}
```

I'm working on a *PIC32 Cerebot* board, and the goal is to update an *LCD* with the current mode, direction, and RPM of a stepper motor. I'll clarify what I can and post anything needed.

Answer (score 0):

sprintf composes a string and stores it in an array that must be big enough: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

In your code, the output buffer you pass to sprintf is declared as

```
char f_LCD_str;
```

which is not an array but a single character. sprintf will inevitable overflow.
A good declaration would be

```
char f_LCD_str[30];
```

(same remark for your other char arrays: f_mode_str and f_dir_str)

It is always safer to use snprintf in order to avoid overflow risks. In which case the call would be:

```
sprintf(f_LCD_str, 30, "%s %s %d", f_dir_str, f_mode_str, f_RPM);
```

note: &f_RPM will print the address of the variable, where f_RPM will print out the variable value, depending on what you want.

Comment: I'll have to try this tomorrow, thank you very much!

Comment: Have you made progress on this? Vote up + accept answer if problem solved is much appreciated. Thanks